# Extract Facebook comments with python

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, extract, facebook-comments

1- I would like to know why I can't extract the text reviews of Facebook pages from graph API v2.10 despite being visible to everyone from the link.

2- What is the best way to extract comments from the page feed. Currently I am using the code below and my problem is that comments with smiley haven't been extracted.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import requests
import json
import sys  

reload(sys)  
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')

def extractCommentFromPage(page_name):
    ACCESS_TOKEN = '*REDACTED*'
    base_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'
    node = base_url + page_name + '/feed/'
    fields = 'comments{message}'
    url = '%s?fields=%s&access_token=%s' % (node, fields, ACCESS_TOKEN,)
    page_name_File = open('unclassified/' + page_name + '.txt','w')
    web_response = requests.get(url)
    j = web_response.json()

    i = 0
    comments = []
    try:
        for k in j['data']:
            for e in k['comments']['data']:
                i = i + 1
                print 'Extracting comments from ' + page_name + ' #' + str(i)
                comments.append(e['message'].encode('utf-8'))
                page_name_File.write(e['message'].encode('utf-8') + "\n\n")
    except Exception as e:
        print e.message
        pass
    return set(comments)
```

Comment: If that's a genuine access token you might want to invalidate it and start using a new one.

Comment: holden was faster than me, but you should most definetly immediately reset your access token if it is a valid one

Comment: 1. UI != API. Just because you can see something on facebook.com, must not automatically mean it is freely accessible via API as well. 2. There is no reason why the API would treat a post “with smilie” any different than one without. So the problem is likely rather in your code, that processes the result. Make the same request in Graph API Explorer, and check if the posts you are looking for are shown there.